The log.html misses captured images when output folder is relocated out of Robotframework repo
I am using robotframework to automate the system tests for the embedded sw. After executing the tests, the log.html, output.xml and report.html are saved in Output folder inside the robotframework repo. The system tests in the output folder have some images generated while running the tests. If I open the report keeping Output folder inside the robotframework repo then all images are displayed like the following.

But if I relocate the Output folder to some other place, then the images are not displayed and the log.html file looks for the images in the Output folder placed in the robotframework repo instead of the new location of the Output folder.

The implementation of plotting the images is given below:
def plot_data(
    self,
    data: Data,
    *,
    title: Optional[str] = None,
    marker: str = "o",
    markersize: float = 2.0,
):
    """Plots the data given and adds it to the report file generated by
    Robot Framework. A .png for the plotted data is also available in the
    same location as the report file."""

    testcase, outputdir = self._get_test_variables()
    plttitle = title if title is not None else testcase
    filetitle = self._strip_string_for_path(plttitle)

    fig_path = os.path.join(
        outputdir,
        f'{filetitle}-DataVerification-{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}.png',
    )

    plt.title(plttitle)
    plt.xlabel(data.x_label)
    plt.ylabel(data.y_label)
    plt.plot(
        data.x, data.y, label=data.y_label, marker=marker, markersize=markersize
    )
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(fig_path)
    self._log_plot(fig_path)
    plt.close()

Here the outputdir and fig_path are absolute path to the Output folder in the Roboframework repo. The robotframework repo is the folder where out whole auto-test framework lies.
Does anyone have seen the same issue? Any solution?
After result folder "Output" has been generated by robot.rebot() function, I have tried to change output.xml file by changing the path to the png images and regenerate the log.html file, but it did not work for me. I also tried to make the output.xml to ignore the absolute path to the output folder in the robotframework and always tried to search for .png images in the current folder but I could not find the way in python.

On your code you have:
fig_path = os.path.join(
  outputdir,
  f'{filetitle}-DataVerification-{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}.png',
)

### extra stuff removed
self._log_plot(fig_path)

So, what probably happens is that the log.html now has absolute path to the image and if  you move the report with the images to a different machine and/or directory, those absolute links wont work and you get a broken image.
Your options are:

Do not store the path name to the log (can't say how since i dont know your _log_plot implementation)
Make your _log_plot read the actual generated image, convert it to base64 and store the string in the img tag's data-srcattribute. This way the image is embedded into the log.html and will always work..


Thanks for the reply Rasjani. Yes, you are right that log.html has the absolute path to the image. Actually I had been working on finding the solution for that and I wanted make the image plot function to take the image from the current folder instead of calculating the path from skratch. Luckly I managed to implement it. So the following change has been made. For self._log_plot(fig_path) the fig_path shall be                                    fig_path = os.path.join(
"./",
f'{filetitle}-DataVerification-{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}.png',
)
